# Can't add a panel (so background) to my JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, background-image

I have a JPanel that I use as a background which name is BackgroundPanel. And I am designing my main JFrame with NetBeans, and adding BackgroundPanel like that.

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Image img = null;
    public Main() {
        initComponents();
        setTitle("Count To");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        Image img = null;
        try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/bg.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("Image can't found.");}

        BackgroundPanel bgPanel = new BackgroundPanel(img, BackgroundPanel.SCALED, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(bgPanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        //setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setForeground(java.awt.Color.red);
        setIconImage(getIconImage());

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

But my BackgroundPanel is not visible, that is there is no background image of my frame, but plain gray (which is default).

I hope my explanation was clear. I can include BackgroundPanel class too if you need it.

Comment: Change your layout manager form GroupLayout to BorderLayout. Alternatively, set the BackgrounPane as the content pane for the frame

Comment: setting BackgroundPanel as contentPane worked like charm, thanks! Can you explain me what is exactly going on there, i would like to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All top level containers (and `JInternalFrame`) have what's called a "Root Pane".  This is responsible for actually building the primary layout of the window.

The root pane consists (basically) of content pane and a glass (and option menu bar), which sit on top of the window.

[image]

When you add components to the window, they are actually been added to the content pane.

In your case, it makes sense to simply replace the content pane with your own panel rather then trying to add it to the existing one.

This way, when you add new components to the window, they will actually be added to the `BackgroundPane` instead.

Make sure though, you change the content pane BEFORE you try adding any components to the window ;)

Check out [How to use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details